# psql cmd command using old user

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-15

I forgot my password for an older version of Postgres (I believe v14) and uninstalled it then deleted the remaining files in my program files folder.

I also deleted the environment variable in the path leading to it.

I installed the latest version, v15.
I set the path variable to include `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin`

v15 works perfectly fine. When I do `psql -U postgres`
I can log in.

None of my passwords work for it, I get

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "chris"
```

**However**, simply typing `psql` in the Power Shell asks me for an old user, of which I forgot the password (the above user, "chris").

PgAdmin does not have this user listed, nor any databases associated with it, only the new Postgres user with v15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is no user `chris` in your new v15 cluster. You'd have to create it:

```
psql -U postgres
...
postgres#> CREATE ROLE chris LOGIN;
CREATE USER
postgres#> \password chris
Enter new password for user "chris":
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this. When I add a new user and a new password I still get wrong password for the 'chris' account that was previously created.

Comment: If the user already exists, then only change its password.

Comment: Awesome, it worked.
Weird that when I created a new "chris" user and set the password it was coming back as wrong password still.

When I removed the new chris user for V15 and then did the steps you mentioned it worked.

I appreciate your assistance!